# nuxt 3 and referer header, referrer header comes back as undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I need to store and then use the referrer header. What I am wanting to achieve is to get the referrer header and then store it in a cookie, that I can access and use to populate an axios request further down the user journey.

I am currently doing the following in my `app.vue`

```
const headers = useRequestHeaders();
console.log("headers", headers['referrer']);
```

I have a set up a redirect from `http://localhost` to `http://localhost:3000` however the referrer header is undefined, how can I the referrer of my user.

Comment: I'm sure you're running this in a browser. yes in the browser there will be no header at all it is only available if the code runs on the server

Comment: The console.log logs to my terminal/server instance. If thats the case you can't get the referrer, how do I log where my users are arriving from?

Answer (score 0):

Since the nuxt is running on both client side and server side, you should get the `referrer` header in a plugin instead of `app.vue`, then store the value into a pinia store, after this, you can use it anywhere in your nuxt project.

---

create a new plugin first

```js
// plugin/initial.ts
// any name you want but without the `.client.[js|ts]` or `.server.[js|ts]` tail
// which will let the code run in client side or server side only

export default defineNuxtPlugin(async (nuxtApp) => {

    const referrer = useRequestHeaders('referrer');

    const referrerStore = useReferrerStore(nuxtApp.$pinia as Pinia);
    referrerStore.setReferrer(referrer);
});
```

then add a pinia store

```js
// store/referrer.ts

import { defineStore } from 'pinia';

export const useReferrerStore = defineStore('referrer', {
    state: () => ({
        _referrer: {}
    }),
    getters: {
        referrer: (state) => stats._referrer
    },
    actions: {
        setReferrer (value: string | undefined | null) {
            this._referrer = value;
        }
    }
});
```

---

now you can use it anywhere you want in your nuxt project.

```js
useFetch(
    '/my/api',
    {
        headers: {
            referrer: useReferrerStore().referrer
        }
    }
);
```

---

> I have a set up a redirect from http://localhost to http://localhost:3000 however the referrer header is undefined, how can I the referrer of my user.

Since you redirect the user from `http://localhost` to `http://localhost:3000`,
you may need to add some configs for your nginx to set the `Referer` header.

```
server {
    listen 80;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header Referer $http_referer;
    }
}
```